# how can optimize this sql query for being faster than superman

Tags: mysql, jdbc

this my sql query:

```
 SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM ClassifiedAd
        WHERE city_id = :city
        AND currency = :currency
        AND price > 100) 

    UNION DISTINCT

    (SELECT c.* FROM 
    ClassifiedAd c 
    WHERE c.city_id = :city
    AND c.currency = :currency
    AND (c.price > 100 AND c.price < c.price_last))" 
    ) l,                    
    ClassifiedAd a
    LEFT JOIN Picture p ON a.id=p.classifiedAd_id
    LEFT JOIN Business b ON b.id=a.business_id
    WHERE a.id = l.id 
    AND (a.price between :priceDown AND :priceUp) 
    AND a.subCategory_id IN (:apartamentList) 
    AND a.category_id = :category 
    AND a.district_id = :district 
    AND a.datePosted > :date 
    AND b.status = :bStatus AND a.adStatus = :cStatus AND (b.premium OR b.businessPlus OR b.excellence )
    ORDER BY -a.business_id DESC LIMIT :limit
```

Simplify QUERY:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    (SELECT * FROM ClassifiedAd
     WHERE city_id = 417
     AND price > 100) 
    UNION DISTINCT
     (SELECT c.* FROM 
      ClassifiedAd c 
      WHERE c.city_id = 417
      AND (c.price > 100 AND c.price < c.price_last)) 
      ) l,                  
      ClassifiedAd a
      LEFT JOIN Picture p ON a.id=p.classifiedAd_id
      LEFT JOIN Business b ON b.id=a.business_id
      WHERE a.id = l.id 
      AND a.category_id is not null
      AND a.district_id is not null
      AND a.datePosted > '2014-12-12'
      AND b.status = 'ACTIVE' AND a.adStatus = 'ACTIVE' AND (b.premium OR b.businessPlus OR b.excellence )
      ORDER BY -a.business_id DESC ;
```

CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `ClassifiedAd` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `parent_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `son_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `title` varchar(512) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `titleOriginal` varchar(512) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `phoneOriginal` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `description` text collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `datePosted` datetime NOT NULL,
  `dateLastModified` datetime default NULL,
  `dateValidated` datetime default NULL,
  `dateLastRenewed` datetime default NULL,
  `timesRenewed` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` float default NULL,
  `price_last` float default NULL,
  `dateLastModifiedPrice` date default NULL,
  `professionalSeller` tinyint(1) default NULL,
  `city_id` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `district_id` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `province_id` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `region_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `town_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `country_code` char(2) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `category_id` varchar(90) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `subCategory_id` varchar(45) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `adType` enum('OFFERING','WANTED') collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `adStatus` enum('ACTIVE','INACTIVE','BLOCKED','PENDING','DELETED','OUTDATED') collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `adLanguage` enum('EN','AR','FR') collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `orderGroup` enum('A','B','C','D','E','F') collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `contactLanguages` char(30) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `adSpecialization` enum('REAL_ESTATE','VEHICLE','JOB') collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `locationUrl` varchar(2048) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `currency` char(3) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `clientRef` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `business_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `agentInstanceId` varchar(32) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `needsReview` tinyint(1) default NULL,
  `needsReviewPhoto` tinyint(1) default NULL,
  `source_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `qualityScore` int(3) default NULL,
  `quotaScore` int(3) default NULL,
  `lastIndexTime` datetime default NULL,
  `user_validator_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `referredUrl` varchar(2048) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `greylistOk` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `greylistInfo` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `greylistReviewed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `whitelistOk` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `whitelistInfo` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `whitelistReviewed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `sanityOk` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `sanityInfo` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  `photoOk` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `forceIndex` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `promotion_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `nitroBoost` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `lastModifiedFromBackoffice` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `promoted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `lastPromotionDate` date default NULL,
  `promotionSortDate` datetime default NULL,
  `dailyPromoted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `categorizationValidated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `topAd` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `shortterm` tinyint(1) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `fk_ClassifiedAd_User` (`user_id`),
  KEY `locationUrl` (`locationUrl`(333)),
  KEY `country_code` (`country_code`),
  KEY `adStatus` (`adStatus`),
  KEY `agentInstanceId` (`agentInstanceId`),
  KEY `needsReview` (`needsReview`),
  KEY `source_id` (`source_id`),
  KEY `source_id_adStatus` (`source_id`,`adStatus`),
  KEY `source_id_category_id` (`source_id`,`category_id`),
  KEY `business_id` (`business_id`),
  KEY `lastIndexTime` (`lastIndexTime`),
  KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
  KEY `clientRef` (`clientRef`),
  KEY `fk_Promotion_id_idx` (`promotion_id`),
  KEY `categorizationValidated` (`categorizationValidated`),
  KEY `phone` (`phone`),
  KEY `fk_Parent_id_idx` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `categorizationValidated_idx` (`categorizationValidated`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5179370 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci$$
```

AND EXPLAIN IN TEXT(JSON):

```
    {
    'id' : 1,
    'select_type' : 'PRIMARY',
    'table' : '<derived2>',
    'type' : 'ALL',
    'possible_keys' : NULL,
    'key' : NULL,
    'key_len' : NULL,
    'ref' : NULL,
    'rows' : 116520,
    'Extra' : 'Using temporary; Using filesort'
},
{
    'id' : 1,
    'select_type' : 'PRIMARY',
    'table' : 'a',
    'type' : 'eq_ref',
    'possible_keys' : 'PRIMARY,adStatus,business_id,category_id',
    'key' : 'PRIMARY',
    'key_len' : '4',
    'ref' : 'l.id',
    'rows' : 1,
    'Extra' : 'Using where'
},
{
    'id' : 1,
    'select_type' : 'PRIMARY',
    'table' : 'b',
    'type' : 'eq_ref',
    'possible_keys' : 'PRIMARY,status',
    'key' : 'PRIMARY',
    'key_len' : '4',
    'ref' : 'mubawab.a.business_id',
    'rows' : 1,
    'Extra' : 'Using where'
},
{
    'id' : 1,
    'select_type' : 'PRIMARY',
    'table' : 'p',
    'type' : 'ref',
    'possible_keys' : 'fk_Picture_ClassifiedAd1',
    'key' : 'fk_Picture_ClassifiedAd1',
    'key_len' : '5',
    'ref' : 'mubawab.a.id',
    'rows' : 5,
    'Extra' : ''
},
{
    'id' : 2,
    'select_type' : 'DERIVED',
    'table' : 'ClassifiedAd',
    'type' : 'ALL',
    'possible_keys' : NULL,
    'key' : NULL,
    'key_len' : NULL,
    'ref' : NULL,
    'rows' : 1592432,
    'Extra' : 'Using where'
},
{
    'id' : 3,
    'select_type' : 'UNION',
    'table' : 'c',
    'type' : 'ALL',
    'possible_keys' : NULL,
    'key' : NULL,
    'key_len' : NULL,
    'ref' : NULL,
    'rows' : 1592432,
    'Extra' : 'Using where'
},
{
    'id' : NULL,
    'select_type' : 'UNION RESULT',
    'table' : '<union2,3>',
    'type' : 'ALL',
    'possible_keys' : NULL,
    'key' : NULL,
    'key_len' : NULL,
    'ref' : NULL,
    'rows' : NULL,
    'Extra' : ''
}
```

]
[image]

I'm working with mysql and jdbcTemplate. 
There is some way to make this query faster? 
I appreciate any help.

Comment: This doesn't seem a valid query. Some mistake during copy-paste, probably.

Comment: Please add the EXPLAIN output as text, not image. It would be better if you also added the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` outputs for all tables involved.

Comment: Please replace the explain output with something like you see in the very first example here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html - that would be actually readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of this UNION adds nothing extra, remove it.  That will save a table scan of ClassifiedAd (1,592,432 rows) and a DISTINCT.

```
              ( SELECT  *
                    FROM  ClassifiedAd
                    WHERE  city_id = 417
                      AND  price > 100
              )
            UNION  DISTINCT 
              ( SELECT  c.*
                    FROM  ClassifiedAd c
                    WHERE  c.city_id = 417
                      AND  (c.price > 100
                              AND  c.price < c.price_last)
              )
```

Add INDEX(city_id, price)

If city_id is a number, why is it declared VARCHAR(255) CHARSET utf8?  Change to SMALLINT UNSIGNED or something suitable.

Note that the optimizer *started* with the subquery (the UNION).  This is because there is no index on the subquery (until 5.6.4).  Upgrading would help, but not nearly as much as the rest of my suggestions.

`country_code char(2) charset utf8` and `currency char(3) charset utf8` -- make them CHARSET ascii; this will change the space from 6+9 bytes to 2+3 for those two fields.

Don't use FLOAT or DOUBLE for monetary values; use DECIMAL(..,4) or something precise like that.

Do not INDEX flags or other things with low cardinality; the optimizer will probably never use those indexes.

The first of these is redundant; DROP it:

```
  KEY `source_id` (`source_id`),
  KEY `source_id_adStatus` (`source_id`,`adStatus`),
```

Check that key_buffer_size is about 20% of available RAM.

Clean up similar things; then the query will run much faster.  Then we can make another pass at performance, if you like.

Comment: I delete union and create index. It's really faster now. ty!!